Знаки препинания после "и вообще" и "но нет"
Оправдано ли двоеточие в предложениях (даю с контекстом):
— Бьешь прямо по больному! Тебе говорили, что ты похож на Вуди Аллена, а? — поинтересовался он.
— Нет. И вообще:(?) не до фильмов в нынешнее время.
Я бы на месте заключенных давно сговорился и устроил переворот. Но нет:(?) все тихонько сидят, жду окончания своих сроков.

Пример 1
Нет. И вообще — не до фильмов в нынешнее время.
Сравним:  Да и вообще не до фильмов в нынешнее время. Это присоединительный союз "да и вообще", знаков нет. Но можно поставить интонационное тире (не двоеточие), чтобы обозначить паузу и подчеркнуть обобщение.
Примечание. В различных учебных материалах слову "вообще" посвящены целые ПОЭМЫ: во вступлении говорится о различной синтаксической роли слова (наречие, вводное слово, частица, союз), а далее следует длинный перечень рекомендаций (когда и что писать). Но я предпочитаю работать с источниками и по ним делать выводы.  И вот лучшим источником является толковый словарь для слова вообще.
 ВООБЩЕ. I. 5. (обычно с союзом и). Разг. Употр. как 
 обобщающее слово перед итогом, заключением. Он читал, гулял 
 - в. наслаждался жизнью. Я простудился, и в. мне очень 
 плохо

Пример 2
Но нет — все тихонько сидят, жду окончания своих сроков.
В этом предложении тире также интонационное, но оно использовано  для обозначения увеличенной паузы вместо запятой.
В приведенном предложении аналогичный случай: желательно использовать тире, а не двоеточие. У двоеточия примерно та же функция при обозначении паузы, но здесь оно не выглядит обоснованным.
